# 500 internal error at wp_generate_attachment_metadata

Tags: attachments

I found that my PHP script throws an 500 (Internal Server Error) at the line which `wp_generate_attachment_metadata` function is used:

```
$attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $fullpathfilename );
```

I can exit and take an output before this line but not after that.

I checked the inputs too:

```
Array
(
    [attach_id] => 101362
    [fullpathfilename] => /home/appleapp/USER/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Beat-the-Boss-2-17+945428.png
)
```

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Have you check this [http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-wp-smushit-http-error-with-wordpress-31] ?

Comment: @Rorschach yes, differs from mine.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to require once this file:

```
wp-admin/includes/image.php
```

Answer (score 0):

[`wp_generate_attachment_metadata()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_generate_attachment_metadata) should be used in conjunction with [`wp_update_attachment_metadata()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_attachment_metadata). So your code should look something like this. (quote from the codex).

> To generate attachment metadata for attachment with parent post ID 37:
>
> ```
> <?php
>   $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $filename, 37 );
>   $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $filename );
>   wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id,  $attach_data );
> ?>
> ```

Comment: Yes it has `wp_update_attachment_metadata` following.